# break down by weeks in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

Given this query:

```
DECLARE 
@FROM_DT DATETIME, 
@TO_DT     DATETIME

BEGIN
SET @FROM_DT = '10/01/2009' 
SET @TO_DT   = DATEADD(DAY,7,@FROM_DT)
--WHILE (@FROM_DT <= '10/01/2010')
WHILE (@TO_DT < '10/01/2010')


BEGIN
SELECT 
CONVERT(CHAR(10),@FROM_DT,101)               AS FROM_DT, 
CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,-1,@TO_DT),101) AS TO_DT,
COUNTRY                                      AS CITZ,
COUNT(SUBJECT_KEY)                           AS PEOPLE
FROM MYTALE
WHERE DATE_DT >=@FROM_DT
AND DATE_DT   <@TO_DT
GROUP BY COUNTRY

SET @FROM_DT = DATEADD(DAY,7,@FROM_DT)
SET @TO_DT     = DATEADD(DAY, 7,@TO_DT)
END
END
```

Here are my results:

```
FROM_DT TO_DT       COUNTRY PEOPLE
10/01/2009  10/07/2009  A       2
10/01/2009  10/07/2009  B       1

FROM_DT TO_DT       COUNTRY PEOPLE
10/08/2009  10/14/2009  A       1
10/08/2009  10/14/2009  C       2

 ---to
FROM_DT TO_DT       COUNTRY PEOPLE
09/23/2010  09/29/2010  A       1
09/23/2010  09/29/2010  B       3

FROM_DT TO_DT       COUNTRY PEOPLE
09/30/2010  10/06/2010  C       13
09/30/2010  10/06/2010  D       1
```

Question:

Is there a way in SQL that it can write the output like below? (I need to consolidate the data. I could copy and paste them but it's 52 weeks of data. Not a efficient way to do it) Please help. I use SQL Server 2005 & 2008 version.

```
FROM_DT TO_DT       COUNTRY PEOPLE
10/01/2009  10/07/2009  A       2
10/01/2009  10/07/2009  B       1
10/08/2009  10/14/2009  A       1
10/08/2009  10/14/2009  C       2
09/23/2010  09/29/2010  A       1
09/23/2010  09/29/2010  B       3
09/30/2010  10/06/2010  C       13
----
```

From the query above, i commented the WHILE (@FROM_DT <= '10/01/2010') out and replaced it with WHILE (@TO_DT < '10/01/2010') because I would like to get the data for FY10 only, which the date starts from 10/1/2009 to 9/30/2010. However, the result only up to 9/29/2010, the data from 9/30/2010 is not included. Is something wrong with my query? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Well, SQL Server has a function called `DATEPART` which can also give you the `WEEK` part of a date - something like:

```
SELECT 
  DATEPART(WEEK, DATE_DT)
  Country AS CITZ,
  COUNT(Subject_Key) AS PEOPLE
FROM dbo.MyTable
GROUP BY 
   Country, DATEPART(WEEK, DATE_DT)
```

This gives you the numeric week number (but not yet the from_date and to_date).

Or you could leave your basic query alone, but store the results into a temporary table:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tmp_Results(FromDT CHAR(10), ToDT CHAR(10), 
                             Country VARCHAR(100), Count INT)
```

and then just insert your results into that table for each run:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.tmp_Results(FromDT, ToDT, Country, Count)
  SELECT 
     CONVERT(CHAR(10),@FROM_DT,101)               AS FROM_DT, 
     CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,-1,@TO_DT),101) AS TO_DT,
     COUNTRY                                      AS CITZ,
     COUNT(SUBJECT_KEY)                           AS PEOPLE
  FROM MYTALE
  WHERE DATE_DT >=@FROM_DT
  AND DATE_DT   <@TO_DT
  GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

and then select from that temp table in the end:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tmp_Results
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursive CTEs to the rescue!  No need for temporary tables anymore since you can generate your set on the fly, and can start the weeks at any date instead of on Monday.

(Danger: Written in notepad.  Minor bugs / typos may be present.  Right idea, though)

```
WITH weeks (start, end) AS (
  select
    @from_dt as start
    dateadd(day, 7, @from_dt) as end
  UNION
  select
    dateadd(day, start, 7)
    dateadd(day, end, 7)
  from
    weeks
  where
    start < @last_dt
)
select
  w.start,
  w.end,
  c.country,
  count(c.subject_key)
from
  my_table c
  join weeks on c.date_dt >= start and c.date_dt < end
group by
  start, end, country
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dynamic query with a union clause, but what I would do is create a temporary table and insert your results into it.  Then you could select out the data from there and drop the temp table.

Your other option would be to create a table that held on to the from-to dates for your weeks and join on that table instead.  This would actually be a preferred way to do it, but you would need to keep that table up to date with all of the dates you need.

Answer (score 0):

An approach from data warehousing would be to create a "Weeks" table with all your possible weeks in it, along with their start and end dates:

```
Week    StartDate   EndDate
1       10/01/2009  10/07/2009
2       10/08/2009  10/14/2009
3       10/15/2009  10/21/2009
...
```

...and then just join to that. You fill the "Weeks" table once, in advance -- you can fill it up to the year 3000 if you want -- and then it's available in your database to do queries like this:

```
SELECT 
  StartDate, EndDate, COUNTRY, COUNT(SUBJECT_KEY) AS People
FROM 
  MYTALE INNER JOIN Weeks ON DATE_DT BETWEEN StartDate AND EndDate
GROUP BY 
  StartDate, EndDate, Country
```

This often simplifies complicated queries when you need to do data analysis over a range of dates (and you can pre-build a similar "days" or "months" table.) It can also be faster, assuming you've indexed the tables appropriately. These tables are "time dimensions" in star schema data warehouse parlance.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE 
@FROM_DT DATETIME, 
@TO_DT     DATETIME

BEGIN
SET @FROM_DT = '10/01/2009' 
SET @TO_DT   = DATEADD(DAY,7*53,@FROM_DT)

SELECT 
CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,7*(WEEKNO),@FROM_DT),101)   AS FROM_DT, 
CONVERT(CHAR(10),DATEADD(DAY,7*(WEEKNO)+6,@FROM_DT),101) AS TO_DT,
COUNTRY                                                  AS CITZ,
COUNT(SUBJECT_KEY)                                       AS PEOPLE
(SELECT M.*, TRUNC(DATEDIFF(DAY,@FROM_DT,DATE_DT)/7) WEEKNO
 FROM MYTALE M
 WHERE DATE_DT >=@FROM_DT
 AND DATE_DT   <@TO_DT) SQ
GROUP BY COUNTRY, WEEKNO

END
```